# JTree lazy loading how to individually setAllowChildren

Tags: java, swing, tree, lazy-loading, jtree

Helle, I want to view the content of a repository in a JTree. For better performance I am lazily loading the childs only when a node will be expanded. This works, only problem is that even "files" are shown as "folders".

The criteria if the node is a file (leaf) or a folder (expandable node) is

```
o.getType().getBaseTypeId().toString().equals("CMIS_FOLDER")
```

The whole code:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeWillExpandListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.ExpandVetoException;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.CmisObject;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.ItemIterable;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;

import at.sviss.cmis.SessionHelper;
import at.sviss.gui.dialogs.OutputDialogs;

public class LazyLoadingTree extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Email mail = new Email();
    private OutputDialogs out = new OutputDialogs();

    private boolean loaded = false;
    private static SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    private static String currentDirectory = "/";

    public LazyLoadingTree(String name, boolean hasChildren) {
        add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Lade ...", false));
        setAllowsChildren(hasChildren);
        setUserObject(name);
    }

    public void setSession (SessionHelper sessionHelper) {
        LazyLoadingTree.sessionHelper = sessionHelper;
    }

    private void setChildren(List<LazyLoadingTree> children) {
        removeAllChildren();
        setAllowsChildren(getAllowsChildren());
        for (MutableTreeNode node : children) {
            add(node);
        }
        loaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return false;
    }

    public void loadChildren(final DefaultTreeModel model, final PropertyChangeListener progressListener) {
        if (loaded) {
            return;
        }
        SwingWorker<List<LazyLoadingTree>, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<List<LazyLoadingTree>, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected List<LazyLoadingTree> doInBackground() throws Exception {

                Session session = sessionHelper.getSession();
                CmisObject cmisObject = session.getObjectByPath(LazyLoadingTree.currentDirectory);
                Folder folder = (Folder)cmisObject;
                ItemIterable<CmisObject> items = folder.getChildren();
                List<LazyLoadingTree> children = new ArrayList<LazyLoadingTree>();
                    for (CmisObject o : items)
                        children.add(new LazyLoadingTree(o.getName(), o.getType().getBaseTypeId().toString().equals("CMIS_FOLDER")));
                return children;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    setChildren(get());
                    model.nodeStructureChanged(LazyLoadingTree.this);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                super.done();
            }
        };
        if (progressListener != null) {
            worker.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener("progress", progressListener);
        }
        worker.execute();
    }

    public JTree init() {
        LazyLoadingTree root = new LazyLoadingTree("Alfresco", true);
        final DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
        final PropertyChangeListener progressListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                bar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
            }
        };
        final JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(new TreeWillExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException {
                TreePath path = event.getPath();
                if (path.getLastPathComponent() instanceof LazyLoadingTree) {
                    LazyLoadingTree.currentDirectory = mod(path.toString());
                    LazyLoadingTree node = (LazyLoadingTree) path.getLastPathComponent();
                    node.loadChildren(model, progressListener);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException { }
        });
        tree.setModel(model);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        try {
            ImageIcon folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/folder-16.png"));
            ImageIcon documentIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/doclib-16.png"));
            if (folderIcon != null && documentIcon != null) {
                DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
                renderer.setClosedIcon(folderIcon);
                renderer.setOpenIcon(folderIcon);
                renderer.setLeafIcon(documentIcon);
                tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        MouseListener ml = ( new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
                {
                    final TreePath treepath = tree.getPathForLocation ( e.getX (), e.getY () );
                    Rectangle pathBounds = tree.getUI ().getPathBounds ( tree, treepath );
                    final TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
                    if (path != null) {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();
                        if (node.isLeaf()) {
                            if (pathBounds != null && pathBounds.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu ();
                              JMenuItem menuItemEmail = new JMenuItem("E-Mail");
                              menuItemEmail.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                        mail.attache(sessionHelper, mod(path.toString()));
                                    }
                                });
                                JMenuItem menuItemDetails = new JMenuItem("Details");
                                menuItemDetails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                        out.nodeDetails(sessionHelper.getDetails(mod(path.toString())), null);
                                    }
                                });
                                menu.add(menuItemEmail);
                                menu.add(menuItemDetails);
                                menu.show(tree,pathBounds.x, pathBounds.y + pathBounds.height );
                            }
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
        });
        tree.addMouseListener(ml);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        root.loadChildren(model, progressListener);
        return tree;
    }

    private String mod(String str) {
        str = str.replace(", ", "/");
        str = str.replace("[", "");
        str = str.replace("]", "");
        str = str.replace("Alfresco", "");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: this question can be answerable in the case that value for SwingWorker will be hardcoded in local variable

Comment: JPopupMenu isn't correctly created, use local variable with access definad as setPopupXxx for JTree

Comment: whatever String mod is doing will be in code code line by using Regex, and question why to/String is used

Comment: mod() is used to get a valid path for the repository, JPopupMenu is working, what has the SwingWorker to do with the nodes? I copied this example and modified it for my needings so dont judge me! I am completely new to this. You are telling me the problems, but not the solutions -.-